# What is the direction of the electricity flow in a DC circuit?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

I know that in AC, the direction of the flow of electrons is constantly changing, but this question is for a DC circuit like an LED with a battery.

Does current in such a circuit flow from the - side of a battery to the + side of a battery? This makes sense to me as the negative side wants to get rid of the negative electrons as it has too many, and the positive side wants to gain electrons so they move in that direction.

But recently I've heard that it's actually the other way round? + > -
I've also heard this is to do with how electricity was first discovered and they got it wrong? Now I'm really confused on which way it actually flows, or if it's just the naming of the positive and negative sides of a battery are inverted..

Could somebody shed some light on this? I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: There is a *convention* for the technical direction of the current: positive current flows from the plus pole of a battery to the minus pole by convention. The microscopic details of conduction in a specific medium/conductor are a different thing. In some conductors, like metals, it is actually electrons that flow. In other media, such as ionic solutions, there can be both positive and negative ions that contribute to the current.

Comment: Beginners can be misled by the idea that electrons "flow". In a simple circuit made from say a battery, a lamp, and a switch, each individual electron would take of the order of *one hour* to make a complete loop around the circuit. The idea that when you flick a light switch in your house, electrons somehow travel instantly down the wires from the power station to your house, is completely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direction of current actually is a convention. Before we knew that electrons were the moving charges, people thought that the positive charges were the ones responsible for the current. But it doesn't matter, there are 2 sign flips when you change from negative to positive or visa-versa: one for the direction of current, and another for the sign of the charge. You end up with the same answer as before.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to visualize this is, the conductor in the circuit, for example a metal like copper, is a lattice of aligned atoms. Now, the + charge is like a hole in the lattice in which you have a copper atom that is missing one electron.  This positive charge is flowing from the + pole to the - pole, which is like a hole of one missing electron in the lattice moving towards the - pole.  And it is moving towards the negative pole, because this pole is richer in electrons.  So it is not the electrons that flow through the lattice but the holes (of missing electrons) which are by definition positive charges.  You can also visualize this like a well, or a valley, in which a group of copper atoms have less electrons than their neutral state.  This well shifts through the lattice towards the negative pole.  In reality some electrons also jump into the lattice and race towards the holes (or wells) to fill these up.  These electrons are indeed moving towards the positive pole, but they usually do not shift through the lattice as fast.  The holes (with + charges) are like little vacuum bubbles of missing electrons.  These shift faster.  So the current in this case is a current of electron wells (bubbles of missing electrons in the lattice of the conductor) which are moving towards the negative pole.

Now, something important to understand, is that electric currents differ from water currents in which the pressure created by the flow of water molecules exerts the kinetic energy. Like in a steam engine for example, in which the pressure moves the pistons. Electrical energy is not produced by electrons pushing anything and exerting pressure. The energy turns kinectic when the positively charged molecules are attracted to negatively charged molecules, especially if both are in a solid state and have to physically move towards each other, as they do in a rotary electric motor.

So one could say, in the case of water flowing, it is repulsion, that is the pressure of many water molecules against barriers that produces motion.  In the case of electric currents it is attraction (of opposite charges) in solid objects that produces motion.  Or in the case of a light bulb, produces heat which emits light in certain elements.

Comment: This is a description of current in semiconductors but not in metals. There are no holes in metals. The current is due to the drift of the free electrons. The current going from plus to minus is just a convention with no correspondent in reality.

Answer (score 0):

Current flows from the + side to the - side. However, electrons flow from the - side to the + side. These statements aren't contradictory when you understand what current is.

Comment: Would you mind expanding a bit? As I understand, current is the flow of charge, which is electrons. So the direction of flow of charge and electrons are the same? Is this incorrect?

Comment: You are incorrect. Current is the flow of positive charge which is physically equivalent to the flow of negative charge in the opposite direction.

Comment: Electrons going from the - side to the + side is equivalent to positive charges moving from the + side to the - side. Thus current moves from the + side to the - side.

Answer (score 0):

Reason why current direction is + to - is: Franklin tossed a coin & it landed wrong way!

Explains why diode symbol points WRONG WAY!!

Seriously. I kid you not!